# Why doesn't callback work for Redis on node

Tags: node.js, redis

The following code works on redis version 3.1.2, but when I upgrade the redis libary to 4.1.0, the call back stops working. There is a REDIS server running on localhost with no password. I am using node 16 LTS.

```
'use strict'
import {createClient} from 'redis';
const redisClient = createClient();

redisClient.on('connect', function() {
    console.log('you are now connected');
});
redisClient.on('ready', function() {
    console.log('you are now ready');
});
redisClient.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(`redis error: ${err}`)
});

// added for 4.1.0 because there is no autoconnect.
await redisClient.connect();

await redisClient.set("test","value", function(err, reply) {
    console.log('set complete');
});
```

When I run this on Redis client 3.1.2, I get "set complete" after set is call. On Redis client 4.1.0, I get nothing as if the callback isn't called. The value is set in the REDIS database even if the callback doesn't trigger. I verified the value using redis cli. There are no error messages. I do get the connect and ready event message.

What am I missing here? I am pretty sure it's something simple that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Node Redis 4.x, following semver conventions, introduced many breaking changes. One of them is that it uses promises instead of callbacks. You can read all the details at https://github.com/redis/node-redis.

Comment: Thanks! So to get the key, I would use something like const myValue = await redisClient.get('myKey'). I had tried this before, but it did not work and I got an empty promise instead. However, after your comment, I looked at it again and realized that I forgot to have "await" in front of the redis get. I thank you for your help!

Comment: Happens to the best of us! Glad you got it working.