# Node hangs indefinitely after deleting key from Redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis

**Problem**
I'm encountering an issue in my Node.js application where I successfully delete a key from Redis, but the application hangs indefinitely and does not proceed as expected. I have verified that the key is indeed deleted from Redis, but the program does not exit or continue with the next steps.

> init_redis.js

```
const redis = require('redis');
    const redisClient = redis.createClient({
  password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
  socket: {
    host: process.env.REDIS_HOSTNAME,
    port: process.env.REDIS_PORT,
  }
});

(async () => {
  await redisClient.connect();
})();
...

const delAsync = util.promisify(redisClient.DEL).bind(redisClient);


module.exports = { redisClient, delAsync };
```

route.js

```
router.delete('/logout', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      ...
   
      const response = await delAsync(userId);
  
        
      if (response === 1) {
        console.log("Deleted Successfully!");
        res.status(204).send();
      } else {
        console.log("Cannot delete");
        throw createError.InternalServerError();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  });
```

**Observations**
I have confirmed that the key is deleted from Redis.
The application, however, does not seem to move forward after the deletion.
I've used async/await and checked for errors in my code.

**What I've Tried**
Checked for errors using async/await.
Verified that the Redis connection is stable.
Ensured that other parts of the code are not causing the delay.

**Questions**
What could be causing the application to hang after successfully deleting the key from Redis?
Are there specific best practices for handling asynchronous operations with Redis in Node.js?
How can I troubleshoot and identify the root cause of the application hanging?

**Additional Context**
Node.js version: 16.15.1
Redis version: 4.6.10
Banging my head to the table: 6x

I appreciate any insights or suggestions to help resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at redisClient doc [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#redis-commands), I'm seeing methods that ALREADY return promises (don't take callbacks).  Thus you can't "promisify" them with `util.promisify()`.

So, when you then try to promisify a method that already returns a promise and does NOT accept a callback, the callback that the promisify function passes to monitor it will never get called and the promise that promisify creates will never get resolved and the promise you are awaiting will never resolve or reject and your code will never advance.  The `await` essentially gets stuck.

So, unless you're using a pretty old redisClient, you can just do this:

```
router.delete('/logout', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      ...
   
      const response = await redisClient.DEL(userId);
  
        
      if (response === 1) {
        console.log("Deleted Successfully!");
        res.status(204).send();
      } else {
        console.log("Cannot delete");
        throw createError.InternalServerError();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  });
```

Per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72155237/why-doesnt-callback-work-for-redis-on-node), Node Redis 4.x changed from callbacks to promises for its methods in a breaking change (no longer support callbacks).